# splitting ul into columns

Tags: css, html-lists

I have a list of ul with 9 items, that I want to split into 2 columns. The first one to have the first 4 items and the second column to have the other 5 items.

I used this css

```
ul { -webkit-columns: 2;  -moz-columns: 2; columns: 2; }
```

HTML

```
<div class="footernav">
            <ul class="footer-lt">
                <li><a>Home</a></li>
                <li><a>Resort Overview</a></li>
                <li><a>Photo Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a>Contact Us</a></li>
                <li class="footertextcolor">Phone</li>
                <li>+000 60 275-737<li>
                <li class="footertextcolor">Address</li>
                <li>Armenia, Yerevan,</li>
                <li>G. Hovsepyan </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

but i get 5 items in the first column and 4 in the second. Is there a way I can specify where the break happens?

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, you are probably better off making 2 ul tags. There does not seem to be a way to accomplish 2 unequal columns using that CSS property, unless of course you throw some blank li tags in there when needed.

Comment: The issue I am having with two ul is that they dont line up next to each other. I need them to be next to each other with about 100px distance between them.

Comment: this is my html now 
'<div class="footernav">
    <ul class="footer-lt">
       <li><a>Home</a></li>
       <li><a>Resort Overview</a></li>
       <li><a>Photo Gallery</a></li>
       <li><a>Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="footer-rt">
     <li class="footertextcolor">Phone</li>
     <li>+374 60 275-737<li>
     <li class="footertextcolor">Address</li>
     <li>Armenia, Yerevan,</li>
     <li>G. Hovsepyan 24/3</li>
    </ul>
   </div>'

Comment: You could cheat like I mentioned and add more blank li - http://codepen.io/tylerism/pen/YXEbPJ

BTW - you are missing a closing tag for one of your li and it is creating a blank space